# Change default ant target by command line argument

Tags: java, ant, build-process, build, build-automation

I'm recently assigned a task to make ant be able to build war packages for different environments. I'm almost done except one feature.

The ant accepts an `env` parameter by like `-Denv=DEV`, and use different configuration files to make the war package. But the default target is `start` which will build, deploy and start the tomcat. I don't want ant to deploy the war neither start the server when I pass in the `-Denv=PROD` arg. I only want ant to build the ROOT.war. It's enough.

I know I can just type one more word to achieve this goal, but you know we are all lazy. :D

Does anyone know how to change the default target according to the command line argument?
My requirements are as below:

1. `ant -Denv=DEV` will build, deploy, and start the server
2. `ant -Denv=PROD` will only build the ROOT.war

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest that you define targets in your `build.xml` file called "DEV" and "PROD" and then invoke Ant as:

```
ant DEV
```

or

```
ant PROD
```

If you want to stick with your current approach of using a system property to select the target, then @krock's answer seems to be the way to go.  (But I don't see any advantage in that approach though.)

Comment: Actually, this is what I did in my previous version. But my TL says we may have more ENVs later, like QA and test. So, we'd better not define them in the build.xml.

Comment: Hmmm ... well I don't see how (just) using a system property will do what you want.  If you want to be able to build for "envs" that are not known to the `build.xml` file, you'll need to do funky stuff with `<import>` or something similar.

Comment: Also - note that this is not just "changing the default target".  You actually want to *define* the default target separately from the main `build.xml`.

Comment: Right. Maybe one build.xml is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

You could also load different property files based on the env property:

```
<property file="${env}.properties"/>
```

and in there configure which target to call:

in DEV.properties:

```
default.target=dev.build
```

in PROD.properties:

```
default.target=prod.build
```

and then call the target based on the property:

```
<target name="default">
    <antcall target="${default.target}"/>
</target>

<target name="dev.build">
    ....
</target>

<target name="prod.build">
    ....
</target>
```

by specifying separate property files for each build type you will make it easy to configure other aspects of the build.

Comment: Though Stephen C suggest your solution as an alternative, I think this is similar with his solution. I still need to define different targets for those ENVs.

Answer (score 0):

there is an "if"-Task in the ant-contrib collection. Using this you can
define a default task, that tests for your parameter and calls the required tasks.
You could also define a default behaviour if the dev param is not set.

Answer (score 0):

OK I give up.

after using Ruby/Rails or other morden tools, I found ant is hard to use.

you don't need to learn how to run native command in Ant, just write a `bash` script to run ant and mixed command lines, such as:

```
# my_run.sh

ant package  # assume you have this target in build.xml
cp target.war /opt/tomcat/webapps   # copy this file to tomcat
/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh   # restart tomcat 
/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```